# How to reset settings in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

It's a simple thing and I was pretty sure it's well described, but surprisingly it is not so obvious.

[Here](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/customization/userandworkspace) I've found a detailed description of settings file. As it states it should be `setting.json` file located `%APPDATA%\Code\User\settings.json`, but in my case it's not there.

Can someone give me some help with restoring default settings in Visual Studio Code? I've hidden menu bar by accident and I can't find no way to show it back.

Answer (score 386, accepted):

You can get your menu back by pressing/holding <kbd>alt</kbd>, you can then toggle the menu back on via the View menu.

As for your settings, you can open your user settings through the command palette:

1. Press <kbd>F1</kbd>
2. Type `user settings`
3. Press <kbd>enter</kbd>
4. Click the "sheet" icon to open the settings.json file:

   [image]

From there you can delete the file's contents and save to reset your settings.

---

For a more manual route, the settings files are located in the [following locations](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settings-file-locations):

- Windows `%APPDATA%\Code\User\settings.json`
- macOS `$HOME/Library/Application Support/Code/User/settings.json`
- Linux `$HOME/.config/Code/User/settings.json`

Extensions are located in the [following locations](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/extension-gallery#_where-are-extensions-installed):

- Windows `%USERPROFILE%\.vscode\extensions`
- macOS `~/.vscode/extensions`
- Linux `~/.vscode/extensions`

Comment: Thank you Daniel. I'm a little bit surprised that toggling menu bar visibility isn't saved in settings file, but as far as I understand deleting content of user settings should bring default settings, so this is it. Thanks again.

Comment: removing contents of settings,json worked like a charm thanks for the solution

Comment: For step '4.' you could also type `@modified` in the top-bar and press _Enter_ - will show you just the modified settings. From there you can click each, click the cog ("Manage") and choose _Reset_.

Comment: As of version 1.41.1 on macOS, the key bindings are now in `keybindings.json` under the same directory as `settings.json`.  To restore the default key bindings, just remove changes in  `keybindings.json`.

Comment: Thanks. It's a good way to see the fully JSON settings file that we changed so that we can revert the stuff strange or redundant

Comment: I used your method and also cleaned all the files manually and final approach to uninstalled manually.

Comment: Isn't easier to just uninstall VS Code and start over?

Answer (score 136):

If you want to reset everything, go to `%userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\Code` and delete the whole folder after you uninstall the VS code, then install it again.

Also in `%userprofile%\.vscode` delete extensions folder in case you want to delete all extensions.

Comment: Just deleting the code folder did the trick for me.  Thanks for actually answering the question.

Comment: This answer helped me. I am not sure why the key `y` stopped working in my editor. Disabled all the extensions but it did not work.

Comment: Deleting the "Code" folder in AppData Roaming fixed it for me on Windows. Cleaning out my VS Code settings.json didn't help either. I don't know why the Selected Answer is "hold Alt", that does absolutely nothing.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for, no need to restart, this answer helped me

Answer (score 82):

This may be overkill, but it seemed to work for me (on a Mac):

```
#!/bin/sh

rm -rfv "$HOME/.vscode"
rm -rfv "$HOME/Library/Application Support/Code"
rm -rfv "$HOME/Library/Caches/com.microsoft.VSCode"
rm -rfv "$HOME/Library/Saved Application State/com.microsoft.VSCode.savedState"
```

After I ran that, and restarted VSC, it showed the the "Welcome" screen, which I took to mean that it was starting from scratch.

Comment: Also remove the `.vscode/` dir in your project folder

Comment: Good point, @Pynchia.  In a perfect world, you'd do `git clean -dxf`, but that's a very sharp knife :-)

Comment: Had `Go To Definition` and `Peek Definition` not working and this finally fixed it. Thanks.

Answer (score 37):

If you want to start afresh, deleting the `settings.json` file from your user's profile will do the trick.

But if you don't want to reset everything, it is still possible through settings menu.

[image: settings menu]

You can search for the setting that you want to revert back using search box.

You will see some settings with ***the left blue line***, it means you've modified that one.

[image: search setting]

If you take your cursor to that setting, a gear button will appear. You can click this to restore that setting.

[image: gear button]

You can also use the drop-down below that setting and change it to default.

[image: setting drop down]

Comment: This has to be the best answer if you are looking to get  certain things back. The blue line was key into finding things I've changed.

Comment: If you experimented with iTerm and then removed it, and now your font looks wonky, try this. Worked for me

Comment: If you click the "funnel" icon to the right of the search bar you'll see an option to only show modified settings now.

Answer (score 23):

On Linux environment delete the folder "~/.config/Code" to reset Visual Studio Code Settings.

Comment: but only the user settings here, not all the settings

Comment: On Linux you can use this guide: [Reset all user settings for VSCode (Code OSS) on Linux](https://gist.github.com/superjojo140/171a19c32cb9346361dae50a446a281f)

Answer (score 23):

#### Steps to reset on Windows:

- Press 'Windows-Key"+R , and enter %APPDATA%\Code\User

  [image]

  And delete 'setting.json' at this location.
- Press 'Windows-Key"+R , and enter %USERPROFILE%\.vscode\extensions

  [image]

  And delete all the extensions there.

## EDIT

After two vote downs added images to make it more clear :)

Answer (score 20):

You can reset both the **user and workspace settings** in **VS Code** as shown in the following screenshots

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 15):

1. Go to `Menu Bar`. Click on `File`->`Preferences`->`Settings` [image]
2. On the top right corner of the `Settings` tab, click on the 3 dots button `...`->`Show Modified Settings` [image]
3. You can now reset all the modified settings individually [image]

Answer (score 6):

Go to File -> preferences -> settings.

On the right panel you will see all customized user settings so you can remove the ones you want to reset. On doing so the default settings mentioned in left pane will become active instantly.

Answer (score 2):

The best easiest way I found to reset settings:

Open Settings page (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>):

[image]

Go onto your desire setting section to reset, click on icon and then **Reset Setting** :

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you just need to reset your profile for a quick test, VSCode 1.71 (Aug. 2022) will propose:

> ### [transient profiles](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/158695)
>
> These profiles are deleted automatically once the last window which uses it is closed.
>
> You can create and associate a transient profile from
>
> - CLI by passing `--profile-transient` flag. Eg:
>
>   ```
>   code <folder-uri> --profile-transient
>   ```
> - UI from Command Palette using command `Create Transient Settings Profile`
>
> These will create a transient settings profile and associate it to the workspace.
> Once the workspace is closed (or uses different profile) this profile is deleted.

That can help before going nuclear and deleting your [current profile and VSCode settings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36109176/6309).

This is released to [VSCode Insiders](https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders/) today.

Answer (score 1):

Heads up, if clearing the settings doesn't fix your issue you may need to uninstall the extensions as well.

Answer (score 1):

If all you want to do is "reset perspective" ala Eclipse (and why is this not in Code anyway?) then select [View] -> [Open View] -> [Run and Debug].

This puts all the panes back, this is what most people mean by "reset perspective".

Comment: no, it does not

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [the locations of the 'User' settings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36109176/1919793), the settings specific to a 'Remote' WSL distro:

[image]

are stored in that WSL2 distro at:

`$HOME/.vscode-server/data/Machine/settings.json`

and the `wslpath` in Windows would look like:

`\\wsl.localhost\Ubuntu-22.04\home\ *wslUser* \.vscode-server\data\Machine\settings.json`

Answer (score 0):

I'm just doing an update which worked for me.

SO Windows: Access the directory (using the selected answer as reference)

`Windows %APPDATA%\Code\User\settings.json`, but instead of removing the settings.json file, I've just removed the entired USer folder then restarted the VSCode.

Hope that it can be a quick solution for someone