# Visual Studio Code intellisense not working

Tags: visual-studio, ide, intellisense, visual-studio-code, code-completion

I recently upgraded VS Code to version 1. Before that, intellisense was working fine for all of my files. Right now I am just working in JQuery. However, after the upgrade my intellisense is not working at all.

Hovering over variables or functions the intellisense window opens and stays at Loading...
The other symptom I have seen is that it can't seem to see the definitions of functions I have written. Placing my cursor on a function call and pressing F12 or Goto -> Goto Definition results in nothing.

I have closed and reopened. Tried different files. Opened folders, opened single files. Uninstalled and re-installed the app. No luck.

Comment: Have you tried restoring your settings to default? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36108515/how-to-reset-settings-in-visual-studio-code Reinstalling might not restore to default settings because some programs leave a copy of your previous settings on your computer after uninstalling.

Comment: The link you provided doesn't explain how to reset settings to default.  Someone tried, but the instructions they gave was for Visual Studio and this is for Visual Studio Code.  Resetting the defaults might work as even after re-installing it remembered where I was working last.  Will see if I can figure out how to reset the environment.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out the problem and my apologies as I missed a key piece of information.  I was editing a JS file within a SharePoint library.  I do not know if it is the WebDav component of the connection or just SharePoint, but VS Code will not fully function when pointing at a SharePoint location.  Taking the same file locally allowed all the functionality of Intellisense to work.

Comment: How to know that the file is being at SharePoint location?