# Visual Studio Code - Light bulb not appearing

Tags: visual-studio-code

My Visual Studio Code used to have auto imports. I would type something that is exported in another file, and when hovering over it, a light bulb would appear that I could click on to make the import appear on the top. The light bulb seems to have disappeared. The intellisense is still there, so it knows what exists and what does not, but I have no way to do quick actions.

I have tried the following things to get it back.

- Uninstalled VSCode, deleted the settings and the extensions as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49243496/4410223). Then reinstalled.
- Ensured the settings `Enables the code action lightbulb in the editor` is enabled.
- Restarted PC

Any ideas what else I could try?

Comment: Which version are you using?

Comment: had the same issue of light bulb not appearing with the settings on, but got resolved once VS code was restarted

Answer (score 4):

Try hovering on it and right click to find Quick Actions Light Bulb or else you can hover and use shortcut key ctrl+ '.' to enable the lightbulb

Answer (score 1):

It turns out it is something to do with the typescript version I was using. I am currently using 3.1.1 but I did `npm install typescript@3.0.3` and it fixed the issue. I don't really why this makes a difference, and would love for someone to enlighten me.

Seems to be an issue that is reported [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27640).

Answer (score 0):

I just had to wait several seconds, hovering over the missing import, until "Quick Fix" appeared next to "Peek Problem". After clicking on that, and waiting several seconds more, the command to do auto imports appeared. Very odd to have that kind of delay in a desktop app.