# How do I reset VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I altered vscode to use python and now when using javascript the option to 'open with live server' on a right click of the project is no longer available(replaced by 'run code'), I think the alterations I made, including adding python extensions, has changed the environment to one that can run python but I would like to return to the way it was, how can I do this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try deleting the default settings file. The location varies by platform:

- Windows: `%APPDATA%\Code\User\settings.json`
- macOS:  `$HOME/Library/Applicatio Support/Code/User/settings.json`
- Linux:  `$HOME/.config/Code/User/settings.json`

If that does not help, try deleting extensions located at:

- Windows: `%USERPROFILE%\.vscode\extensions`
- macOS: `~/.vscode/extensions`
- Linux: `~/.vscode/extensions`

Comment: the right path for macOS is $HOME/Library/Applicatio Support/Code/User/settings.json, I couldn't edit the answer because an edit must be at least of 6 characters, here just the "n" in "Applicatio Support" is missing

Answer (score 0):

Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36108515/how-to-reset-settings-in-visual-studio-code/36109176#36109176) answer.

It's easy to reset settings in VSCode.

And you can delete setting from extensions that you don't want one by one in setting file.

> Example, If you would like to reset setting from peacock extension.
>
> You can delete only this line from picture link that help you not reset all setting in
>   VSCode.
>
> [example setting file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZCXph.png)