# Auto Suggestion is not working as expected in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image]

I have been facing this issue for a while now.I tried installing extensions as well for it but still it doesn't seems to resolve the issue of auto suggestions fields visibility.

Comment: Reset your `vscode` to default settings and then try again. Find how to reset to default here

Comment: @HariHaran Thanks for the help.I found the description here to reset default settings https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36108515/how-to-reset-settings-in-visual-studio-code.And now it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Reset your `vscode` to default settings and then try again. Find how to reset to default here

[How to reset settings in Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36108515/how-to-reset-settings-in-visual-studio-code)

**Update**

Looks like resetting to default did work..