# Completion overwrites braces

Tags: visual-studio-code

Somehow enabled this strange behavior, and now can't disable [image: this], what setting controls that?
This is not caused by extension, getting this while running with `--disable-extensions` and with all settings reset to default

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like vscode bug, fixed after downgrade

Didn't find original issue, only [dupe](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/82498)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to do a hard reset.

### Backup your settings

You can use [Settings Sync](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Shan.code-settings-sync).
[Here](https://shanalikhan.github.io/2015/12/15/Visual-Studio-Code-Sync-Settings.html) is a tutorial on how to use it

### Reset completely vscode

By deleting manually the files at the [following locations](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settings-file-locations):

- for Windows `%APPDATA%\Code\User\settings.json`
- for macOS `$HOME/Library/Application Support/Code/User/settings.json`
- for Linux `$HOME/.config/Code/User/settings.json`

And for the [extensions](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/extension-gallery#_where-are-extensions-installed):

- Windows `%USERPROFILE%\.vscode\extensions`
- macOS `~/.vscode/extensions`
- Linux `~/.vscode/extensions`

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36108515/how-to-reset-settings-in-visual-studio-code)

Then restore your settings.