# Probleme returning to a new line automatically (Visual Studio)

Tags: visual-studio

I have a problem in my Visual Studio editor, when I stop typing code, 2 seconds later the editor automatically jumps to a new line!

Please I need to disable this nasty habit:

[image]

Comment: That is not the Visual Studio editor.  Maybe [this bug report](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-go/issues/2426) applies.

Comment: @HansPassant, i think the problem is an extension, can you please show how to fix this problem ?

Comment: Check  my answer!

Comment: This is not "*Visual Studio*". Maybe "*Visual Studio **Code***"? (Similar name, but completely different application.)
I suggest to update the title and tag, because it's misleading.

Answer (score 1):

This is problably some config you made; try to:

First end the process by Admin Task panel and them open again to check if that change you made its only persist in that session, if you open again and the problem persist I recommend you this:

To reset everything(your VSC config and the extensions), go to `%userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\Code` and delete the whole folder **after you uninstall the VS code**, then install it again.

Also in `%userprofile%\.vscode` delete extensions folder in case you want to delete all extensions.
[Here the info from file settings.](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settings-file-locations)
But probably if you want to start afresh, deleting the settings.json file from your user's profile will probably do the trick.

[Here another post which is similar to your problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36108515/how-to-reset-settings-in-visual-studio-code)

I simulated your problem
`"editor.formatOnSave": true` is triggering the issue. The same happens if I set `python.formatting.formatOnSave": true`.