# Prevent Visual Studio Code from opening ESLint documentation in my web browser

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, eslint

Visual Studio Code auto corrects my ESLint errors when saving my TypeScript files.

Now, every time when I save a file containing ESLint errors, VS Code opens the online ESLint documentation for every ESLint error I have. If I have 7 ESLint errors, it would open 7 tabs in my web browser...

Probably I enabled this with a short key?

How can I turn this off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently this configuration setting was added to my settings.json file.

```
"eslint.codeAction.showDocumentation": {

}
```

Removing this, solved the issue.

Here you can see [how to open the settings.json file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36109176/1712944).