# How to Completely Reset Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, reset

Hello Does Anyone know how to COMPLETELY Reset VSCODE?(AS IF I WAS DOWNLOADING FOR THE FIRST TIME)

Answer (score 3):

delete default settings file

Windows location %APPDATA%\Code\User\settings.json

Comment: You may also need to reinstall vscode after this. See this similar thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36108515/how-to-reset-settings-in-visual-studio-code