# Visual Studio Code intellisense

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

After the last several updates of VSC I got the next problem.
Usually when I code something on html, I write <di, then get several hints where I choose div, press TAB button and receiver .
But now this thing doesn't work at all. When I press TAB nothing happens.
What can this be and how can this one be solved?

Answer (score 1):

for working with html, it's common to install these `extensions`:

> HTML Snippets

> HTML CSS Support

> IntelliSense for CSS class names in HTML

> CSS Formatter

they will help you in development.

Comment: Thanks, I already have them installed, but still my problem is not solved.

Comment: so update your vs code to latest version, it should solve the problem , but if the problem remains, try to [Reset Settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36108515/how-to-reset-settings-in-visual-studio-code) to default by mentioned link.