# VS code is deleting spaces after tab key and space key (Can't indent)

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

I don't know why, but vs code isn't allowing me to indent. It's deleting any whitespace whenever I press the tab or the space key in the HTML file. I thought it was because of Prettier, but after uninstalling it still does it. I also took off trim auto whitespace.

(settings.json)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**To fix the issue**

Pressing ctrl+M causes the ⇥ Tab key to move focus instead of inserting a ⇥ Tab character.
Turn it off by pressing the shortcut again.

**To disable the shortcut**

Open "Keyboard Shortcuts" with ctrl+K, then ctrl+S.
Or go to File > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts.
Search for toggle tab key moves focus.
Right Click, Remove Keybinding.

Comment: No, it's still deleting the indents

Answer (score 0):

If you check you VSCode on Settings; then at the Search bar type whitespace and you'll be able to see all the options.

VSCode Settings: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQemt.jpg

Comment: I tried un-marking and marking the settings for whitespace and still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Factory resetting vs code & manually deleting extensions files was what fixed the issue.

Below is a link to factory reset vs code and deleting the extensions.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/36109176/13393443

Answer (score 0):

I was about going through factory reset and deleting my extension when I bumped into the cause of the problem - **ucheck "Trim Trailing WhiteSpace" for both user and workspace.** It was like miracle for me. NOTE: I have an extension that saves my work as I type.
Search for "whiteSpace" in setting and proceed to uncheck the button.
[Make sure to uncheck that box for user and workspace too](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jKAb7.png)