# HTML syntax not highlighting correctly

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

The syntax highlighting for .html files does not work.
[image: This is what happens when I open an .html file]

However, highlighting for .css files does work. Any ideas what should I do?

[image: This is what .css files look like]

If anyone might find it important (though none of them affect HTML other than the indentation colors one, and I use the default Microsoft VSCode HTML syntax highlighting), this is the list of my extensions:

[image]

Comment: What language is displayed on the bottom right of VSCode ? Also, make sure there are no extensions that may interfere with the syntax highlighting.

Comment: The language is HTML, no extensions change syntax highlighting for HTML.

Comment: The only extension that changes any highlighting is Babel JavaScript, though it should not change HTML. After disabling it there is no difference.

Comment: Furthermore reseting the settings like here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36108515/how-to-reset-settings-in-visual-studio-code doesn't make a difference.

Comment: Removing the contents of the `%appdata%/Code` folder doesn't help either.

Comment: Does this happen for all HTML files (from any folder) ? Maybe try disabling all extensions just to be sure.

Comment: 1. It does happen for all HTML files.
2. I tried reloading without extensions but it doesn't make a difference

Comment: have you tried different themes

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue. I realised that once when I was meddling with something I added by accident a single character to the beginning of the file `Microsoft VS Code\Resources\App\Extensions\html\syntaxes\html.tmLanguage.json` which made VSCode unable to parse it. The highlighting works now.