# Reset visual studio to the default setting

Tags: visual-studio-code

How can I reset visual studio to the default setting?

Currently it looks like this

[image]

But I would like to leave it like this, which is how it was when I installed it.

**With this default menu**

[image]

Comment: Menu: **View** > **Extensions**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to reset settings in Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36108515/how-to-reset-settings-in-visual-studio-code)

Answer (score 0):

Do a clean install of it. Uninstall and re-run the installer.