# Weird error in Visual Studio Code reverting actions

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code

I was coding then out of no where this random thing that I can't do any type of actions before the get reverted. I can't do backspace, enter, type but only copy paste which was so painful to do until I had to swap to Atom in the mean time cause of this error.

here is the video link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YOV6J.jpg

Please tell me what to do.

Answer (score 0):

I know this might seem dumb but did you try restarting VsCode?  If so, try uninstalling it and downloading it again

Comment: Clear your vscode settings file then, you'll have to go into the program files of vscode to do that

Comment: wait which file is it? Prefrences?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36108515/how-to-reset-settings-in-visual-studio-code