# Can you download a completely new clean copy of VSCode?

Tags: windows

I have tried everything that has been written about uninstalling extensions but I really prefer to download a complete clean copy of VScode and start again.  Is that possible or do I have to sign in under another email?  Totally new to all this and have mucked up my copy!

Answer (score 0):

I asume you would like to have your VScode in default clean state same as it was first installed?

Then after uninstall remove remaining folders or use some app which will look for all folder settings for you and remove them...

or just delete

```
%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code

%userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\Code

%userprofile%\.vscode
```

A lot about reseting VScode to default is here: [How to reset settings in Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36108515/how-to-reset-settings-in-visual-studio-code)?