# Auto adjust size of windows panel when working in split window?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I don't know what I did, but for a while, in a vertically split screen window, whenever my cursor would go to 1 side, the current panel would become wider, and vice versa.

In a new window, I'm not exactly able to make it work.

Is there a specific reason or way to trigger this?

Thank you

Comment: Reset settings https://stackoverflow.com/a/67700660/2658357

Comment: I WANT to figure out how to do it. Not reset all my settings...?