# unable to start php debugger in vscode after php upgrade to 8.0; cannot open browscap.ini

Tags: php, migration, vscode-extensions, php-8

Following my update from php 7.3 to php 8.0,  I am no longer able to debug in VS Code.  I am using the PHP pack extension.

I attempted uninstalling/reinstalling extensions and restarting vscode.

I get the error:

PHP Warning:  Cannot open "C:\XXX\browscap.ini" for reading in Unknown on line 0
PHP Fatal error:  Unable to start standard module in Unknown on line 0

Warning: Cannot open "C:\xXXX\browscap.ini" for reading in Unknown on line 0

Fatal error: Unable to start standard module in Unknown on line 0

Comment: Typically the settings (in php.ini) will be like say `browscap = "C:\xampp\php\extras\browscap.ini"` and the system will be able to work. For your case , please first check whether the browscap.ini exists in C:\xXXX\ (after your have upgraded to the new PHP ).

Comment: yes I definitely have the file,  it doesn't seem to have anything relevant to the issue though.  however the message says cannot open,  perhaps it is a permission issue, but from what I see everyone has read access.

Comment: (A) please double-check the php.ini, if the line is browscap="\xxxx\browscap.ini", then change to browscap="c:\xxxx\browscap.ini". (B), your guess is for sure likely - permission issue.

Comment: hmm php ini seems to have the correct location: [browscap]
; http://php.net/browscap
browscap="C:\xampp_php8_0\php\extras\browscap.ini"
which corresponds correctly to the file location.  is it possible that some php plugin config needs to be updated?

Comment: OK, please try resetting the VScode settings and see the result. (see this [SO_post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36108515/how-to-reset-settings-in-visual-studio-code) )