# VSCode dosen't suggest React Native components or css properties

Tags: visual-studio-code

I just installed VSCode and React Native but when I watched some videos about app development in these I noticed that VSCode suggests React Native components and CSS properties (in app.js) for the user so want to find a way to enable this function or there might be an extension that does it.

here are a couple of images for more clarity (from videos - the results I want)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/cPAPE.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/m7aK1.png

I tried maybe importing all React Native components but it seems to be stupid.
I noticed that in the CSS files VSCode does suggest properties.
VSCode does suggest words I already used.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to reset settings in Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36108515/how-to-reset-settings-in-visual-studio-code)

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a solution. I just reset my VScode settings and it seem to work.
[How to reset settings in Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36108515/how-to-reset-settings-in-visual-studio-code)