# VS code not pasting correctly or at all

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I try to replace code by Pasting code I copied it just leaves the old code there and instead copies the code I was trying to replace. It also does it if I first delete the old code and paste the new one, it just adds the old code again and adds it to my clipboard.

This problem started happening 2 days ago after starting to code in JavaScript. Not sure if that helps but if anyone knows how to fix this please tell me.

Thank you

I have tried changing the binding for pasting and that still hasn't worked. I have copied code then pasted it in notepad and that works it is just vscode.

Comment: As some last resort: [How to reset settings in Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36108515/how-to-reset-settings-in-visual-studio-code)  

Comment: When you say it "copies the code I was trying to replace", do you mean it duplicates it? I'm trying to understand how the first situation you're describing jives with the second one.

Comment: You could try checking if the pasting keybinding has any "same keybindings" that might be firing instead or in addition.

Comment: @wjandrea When I select the code I want to paste ontop of it just doesn't change and if I try to control + v somewhere else (Including outside vs code) it pastes the old code which I tried to replace, its very stange

I have searched to see if anything else is using the same keybinding but there isn't which makes it more confusing

Comment: Another thing worth trying:  Ctrl+Shift+P: `Developer: Reload With Extensions Disabled`, or `Extensions: Disable All Installed Extensions`.  When things get starting to work you will know that is (one of) the extensions.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. Everytime I select something VS Code automatically copies it to my clipboard for some bizarre reason

Comment: There is a setting for this: `terminal.integrated.copyOnSelection` (see: [Copying is done automatically on selection when terminal.integrated.copyOnSelection is enabled](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/terminal/basics#:~:text=Copying%20is%20done%20automatically%20on%20selection%20when%20terminal.integrated.copyOnSelection%20is%20enabled)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).