# Jupyter with VSCode: "execution_count": null / NameError: name 'null' is not defined

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter

**How to produce the error:**

1. Uninstalled and reinstalled Python and VSCode using BCUninstaller.
2. Open VS Code
3. Create a .ipynb file
4. In the first cell run any module (i.e. import collections).
5. Run the cell and get the error show in the image.

**Obs:** I have not typed null instead of Null. That line of code is automatically filled in the source by Jupyter or VSCode. It won't show in any cell.

**Other informations:**

1. I'm using Windows 10
2. I can import any module from the command prompt
3. The file works fine if opened using Jupyter on the browser
4. Might have started to happen after I followed this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7xAJNewv8Gs), which explains how to add extensions (nbextensions) to Jupyter. I was trying to add the capability for Jupyter/browser to collapse headers

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Solved by uninstalling Visual Studio Code and deleting remaining settings files and extensions. For those interested:

Settings are located in the following locations:

- Windows `%APPDATA%\Code\User\settings.json`
- macOS `$HOME/Library/Application Support/Code/User/settings.json`
- Linux `$HOME/.config/Code/User/settings.json`

Extensions are located in the following locations:

- Windows `%USERPROFILE%\.vscode\extensions`
- macOS `~/.vscode/extensions`
- Linux `~/.vscode/extensions`

**Source:** [How to reset settings in Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36108515/how-to-reset-settings-in-visual-studio-code)