# How do I clear all data for Visual Studio Code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, ide

I downloaded vs code about a year ago and flip flopped between it and pycharm, but now I find that I need to get back to vscode I realised I've changed some sort of file setting, where even where I try to execute a simple python function in the terminal, it returns an error. essentially all I want is a hard reset, but everytime I re-install the application it loads up the same like nothing happened, I have deleted all files before reinstalling, and I have never set up an account, so I don't know where they are getting the data from. All I need is a hard reset!!!

I tried removed files, uninstalling and re installing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to reset settings in Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36108515/how-to-reset-settings-in-visual-studio-code)

Comment: May I know what's going on with the problem? If it has been solved, can you change the status of the answer to help more people with similar problems.

Answer (score 1):

You can delete the .vscode folder, which is hidden in your user folder. First, uninstall Visual Studio Code. If you're on a Mac, you can find the .vscode folder in your user directory (go to your hard drive, navigate to 'users,' and then locate your username folder). Now, you should make the hidden folders visible. Again, if you are on a Mac, you can do that by pressing Command + Shift + Dot. Finally, delete the .vscode folder and also remove it from the trash.

Answer (score 0):

You can completely uninstall vscode according to [this link guide](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/uninstall#_clean-uninstall).

> If you want to remove all user data after uninstalling VS Code, you can delete the user data folders `Code` and `.vscode`. This will return you to the state before you installed VS Code. This can also be used to reset all settings if you don't want to uninstall VS Code.